# How to invoke a method based on time

Tags: c#, timestamp

Hi there I am fairly new to programming in C#. How can I make use of a time stamp to control the invocation of a method?

For example, if the time stamp is under a certain number of seconds, invoke one method.
If it's over a certain period of time run, invoke another method.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

This is the code I'd like to use:

`DateTime.Now.Second + DateTime.Now.Minute * 60;`

I know how to use if and else statements. All I want to do is make the computer control when they are activated using time.

Comment: Are you asking "how to write `if (condition) OneMethod(); else OtherMethod();`"? Or something different?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `if-else` statement

```
// Sample usage
var seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
var time = DateTime.Now.Second + DateTime.Now.Minute * 60;
if(time < certainNumberOfSeconds) // Sample Condition.
     // Invoke a method
else
    // Invoke a different method.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secondsUntilRunSecondMethod = (WaitingInSeconds - currentTime.Seconds) % 60;
```

You can use secondsUntilRunSecondMethod in a timer and run the method form the timer.